# Psycopg2 failed with exit status of 1120 on Windows 10

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a `venv` with Python 3.8 installed, updated computer from windows 7 to 10 and now I can't install Psycopg2 nor Psycopg2-binary.

It is giving me the following error:

[image]

I have tried:

- Installing from github with `pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py25#egg=psycopg2`. It still says Psycopg2 is not installed:

  [image]

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See my answer in stack overflow earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638460/got-widnows-error-1120-while-trying-to-install-psycopg2-psycopg2-binary/58638580#58638580

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled my python to 64 bit version (because my laptop is 64-bit) and it works for me. I see that you have the 32-bit version. Just install windowsX86-64 version of python from the official website.

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to install psycopg2 but I am getting this error:  DLL load failed while importing _psycopg. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Do you have installed postgresql and added to global variables a path to pg_config ?

Comment: I do have Postgres installed and it's on the window's path. How can I verify whether it's connected to the pg_config? When I type in "postgres" it gives me this: `postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.`

Comment: Update: Fixed the issue by installing Python 3.7.5. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. It's a very hard error. Spent a day trying to solve.

Comment: Don't even tell me about it, I was on the same boat! Wishing you a good weekend.