# Got widnows error 1120 while trying to install psycopg2/psycopg2-binary

Tags: python, django, windows, psycopg2

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I have installed postgresql and added to the global variables path to pg_config. Windows 8, python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have python 3.8 64bit installed for 64bit machine and python 3.8 32bit for 32bit machine.

Uninstalling old 32bit python and installing 3.8 64 bit for my 64 bit os worked for me to resolve the same issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I literally tried everething what i could google. Your solution works for me.

Comment: You can vote up for this so it will be helpful for others too. I also spend lot of my time resolving this issue and ended up with reinstalling python.